# google app engine(java): gwt gernetated .js file not found

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Hello
  I am using GWT and google app engine in eclipse. and when i compile and run locally it is working perfectly. However, after i deployed myapp to app engine, and the gwt generated .nocache.js files are missing. is there any settings i need to turn on?
 anyone knows why?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you only running in development mode locally?

Are you GWT compiling before you deploy? You will have to run a GWT compile before deploying.